# (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream - Opsworks Rails 4

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, 502-error, opsworks

I deployed a rails 4 application in OpsWorks (Ubuntu 14.04, nginx and unicorn), when I open the homepage I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error. In nginx/error.log I can see this error:

```
2015/01/25 06:19:42 [error] 3652#0: *1 connect() to unix:/srv/www/app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: IP, server: app$
```

For more information here you can see my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes  10;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;


  access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;

  keepalive_timeout  65;

  gzip  on;
  gzip_static  on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types application/x-javascript application/xhtml+xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/css text/javascript text/plain text/xml;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";

  client_max_body_size 4m;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

  upstream unicorn-app {
    server unix:/srv/www/app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

}
```

Updated:

I have added 777 permission for the shared and sockets folder, and also for the unicorn.sock as you can see here:

drwxrwxrwx 9 deploy www-data 4096 Jan 25 06:01 shared

drwxrwxrwx  2 deploy www-data 4096 Jan 25 05:12 sockets

-rwxrwxrwx 1 deploy www-data 0 Jan 25 05:12 unicorn.sock

But I still have the same problem:

```
2015/01/26 21:19:52 [error] 3652#0: *62 connect() to unix:/srv/www/app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: IP, server: app, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/srv/www/app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock:/", host: "ec2-117.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
```

Comment: unicorn is not running, or the path to the socket is wrong.

Comment: if I write ps aux | grep unicorn,here  is the result:
ubuntu   16092  0.0  0.0  10464   932 pts/0    S+   17:29   0:00 grep --color=auto unicorn

Comment: that eliminates one cause - how about the other?

Comment: when I try to enter in the /srv/www/app/shared folder I get "Permission denied" error, I can change the permissions for this folder, but would be good? The shared folder would be a correct location for the unicorn.sock?

Comment: @darkcode, did you ever get this resolved? I am struggling with the exact same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `/srv/www/app/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock` has correct rights for the user nginx's worker processes are running with (`www-data` in your case).

Comment: the permission for the ww-data looks like correctly as you can see in the last update